# Width: Auto not working on dropdown navigation

Tags: html, css

Going to be quite difficult to explain this so I've created a [JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Relborg/Kpxpf/4/) so you guys can see what I mean...

If you look under the 'products' tab the second link in the list I've made quite long, the result is that it overflows out the boundaries of the list. How can I make this that if a link is very long, that the width of the containing ul stretches to contain the link?

Again having a look at the JSfiddle will make things more clear in what's happening and what needs to be done.

PS - Need to get it to work without editing the HTML at all!

```
//Ignore this
```

Comment: As this is a style change (CSS) you will not need to change the HTML but can I ask why you cannot change the HTML? Curiosity is all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the fixed width of your list:

```
ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 140px; // <-- Remove this
    height: 25px;    
}
```

It will make your default width for your list become auto and you're done.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Kpxpf/5/

Comment: I'm presuming that style is for the main navigation and not the dropdowns meaning the width is required, just not on the nested `ul`s.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the `width:140px;` to `min-width:140px;` in `ul li`

Demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/Kpxpf/6/

Comment: It does not look nice if the text is very short then it'll left a lot of redundant space

Comment: @user1479606 that's the way the OP wants it I believe.

Comment: @user1479606 but there should be some similarity in width on all the drop downs otherwise it looks unprofessional.

Answer (score 0):

You're constraining the width of your `<li>`s from the style on the top-level menu. This will keep your intended `width: 140px;` on the top-level menu and allow the sub menu to size based on its content.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/EdFc8/)

```
ul#menu li ul li {
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't default width value is `auto`?

Comment: It is, you're overriding he's overriding it with `width:140px` among other styles when targeting `ul li` though.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a fixed width on the nested lists.

Change the `ul li` styles to:

```
#menu > li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

This will remove the fixed width from the nested `ul`s allowing them to take as much space as needed.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kpxpf/7/)